# thread.h no such file or directory visual studio project

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, include

I'm new to this, just trying to understand how it works. I m using visual studio, opened an existing project running in c++ Release mode, win32. I need to create a thread to be able to run a sequence of instructions. 
In the beginning I created a simple cpp file like the following example and I had no issues: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/. I compiled just the cpp file

But when I add the line #include  in the bigger project, it is marked as an error and compile/ building the project gives me : `Error C0183: Cannot open include file: no such file or directory`

How can I fix that? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Edit : I added this in the beginning of the code, and the main looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread.h>
```

`int _cdecl wmain(_In_ int argc, wchar_t *argv[])    {  // bla bla
    }`

```
Please note that it was running without errors until I added  
 #include <thread.h>, or #include <thread>
```

Comment: consider adding more details about the problem, e.g. your code fragment, the error log shown etc.

Comment: Can you show us how does your thread.h and main code looks like, just the part were you do the include? Did you include with '' instead of <>? Other important thing is to add the file in the correct folder. Give us some extra information please.

Comment: You not need to write `thread.h` but you should just use `#include <thread>`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Please see the message above that I edited. Somewhere I read that "standard threading support is a new feature (defined in the C++11 standard)" but I don't understand how I should fix it

Comment: [`#include <cstdio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio) and [`#include <thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread) would probably a good idea, *But*... you're running VS2010, however, which does **not** include the C++11 threading library. It does implement many of the 03 items, however, but not threading

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way that I be able to make a thread in VS2010?

Comment: @user6812514 You can use Windows threads, or install boost and use its threads. If you're not locked in some way to 2010, there's a free edition of VS 2015.

Comment: I will use boost thank you!

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 predates the standardized `<thread>` but it does have [`_beginthread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.100).aspx) from `<process.h>`. It's far less flexible, though: it can only start functions which have the signature `void (void* arg)`.

The easiest approach is to make your thread entry function a static method of a class, and pass the `this` pointer as that `void* arg`.